# Java Getting data From XML Website to SQL Database

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get data from the website http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml 
to SQL. I'm using Netbeans, so I created a project and wrote a method for parsing the data.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            URL url=new URL( http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml ");
            Document document = builder.parse(url.openStream());





            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Currency");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) { 
                Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                CurrencyPojo currencyPojoObject = new CurrencyPojo();

                currencyPojoObject.setCrossOrder(Integer.parseInt(element.getAttribute("CrossOrder")));
                currencyPojoObject.setKod(element.getAttribute("Kod"));
                currencyPojoObject.setCurrenyCode(element.getAttribute("CurrencyCode"));

                currencyPojoObject.setUnit(Integer.parseInt(element.getElementsByTagName("Unit").item(0).getTextContent()));
                currencyPojoObject.setIsim(element.getElementsByTagName("Isim").item(0).getTextContent());
                currencyPojoObject.setCurrencyName(element.getElementsByTagName("CurrencyName").item(0).getTextContent());
                currencyPojoObject.setForexBuying(Double.parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("ForexBuying").item(0).getTextContent()));
                currencyPojoObject.setForexSelling(parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("ForexSelling").item(0).getTextContent())); 
                currencyPojoObject.setBanknoteBuying(parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("BanknoteBuying").item(0).getTextContent()));
                currencyPojoObject.setBanknoteSelling(parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("BanknoteSelling").item(0).getTextContent()));

                currencyList.add(currencyPojoObject);
            }
```

I'm saving the values to a List, and I want a write a method that makes automatically save the values to an SQL Database. I created EXCHANGE database and created  variables such as ForexSelling, BanknoteBuying etc.

So, how can I get values from the website and automatically save them into the database with using Java?

Comment: How often or on what basis do you want to save the data to the database? Take a look at the APIs [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) .

Comment: I want to get the exchange rate values from 2010 to current time, and want to upgrade the values daily

Comment: It looks like you have the URL link to the today's data. I guess there must be some place on the website to access the same data for different days of the year. Sometimes institutions provide APIs to access such data. In case you can't find a link to find the API you may try contacting them via email, etc., for the same.

Comment: Yeah, I have the URLs for the previous days rates. The URLs look like http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201805/07052018.xml , yyyyMM and  ddMMyyyy type of dates I edited to links. I got the starting and ending dates from user and created a loop for inserting the dates to the link and gets the values to a list.

Comment: Then the `CurrencyPojo` can have a date field and the program is already storing the pojo in a List collection. Once the list is populated with data the application can start writing it to the database using, for example, `JDBC` APIs. What is the problem?

Comment: Yeah the last part was my problem, I couldn't write it to Database because I didn't know how. I'm looking up to JDBC now. Thanks!